# Prevent page reload after ajax form submission

Tags: ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a form in wordpress with ajax. But after the first submision the page itself is called again.

My Form

```
<form class="et_pb_contact_form clearfix" method="post" action="" id="loginform">
<p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_0 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="mail" data-type="input">
    <label for="et_pb_contact_mail_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">E-Mail-Adresse</label>
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" value="" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse" required=""/>
</p>
<p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_1 et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="pw" data-type="input">
    <label for="et_pb_contact_pw_1" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Passwort</label>
    <input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" value="" placeholder="Passwort" />
</p>
<div class="et_contact_bottom_container">                       
    <button type="submit" class="et_pb_contact_submit et_pb_button">Einloggen</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('submit', '#loginform' ,function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'backend_login.php',            
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),            
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === 'true') {
                    window.location = 'main.php';
                }
                else if (data.indexOf("Fehler") !== -1) {
                    alert(data);
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('#loginnote').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I open the page ([domain]/login) and hit the Submit Button the first two XHR occur of which the first one is correct. But where does the second XHR come from, and how to prevent from this? After the site is new loaded and I hit the submit button again, only the correct and third XHR occur.

[image]

Comment: Might there be another event attached to your form during the first call? Check in the DOM inspector.

Comment: @Michael thanks, that's it. Sometimes you are blind. The Divi Theme is adding two Event Listener. Now I have to get rid of them.

Comment: Which should be doable with [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or better yet, prevent the binding in the first place. Sometimes this is possible with `wp_dequeue_script()`, you just need to know the handler.

Comment: It seems not so easy. jQuery('#loginform').off('submit'); doesn't work. removeEventListener also does not work. I think it is because of an anonymous function.

Comment: Like I said, try to find the enqueue handler of the script that binds the events. Of course you cannot dequeue it if it contains other functionality aswell, but maybe you're lucky. Also make sure that your script executes _after_ the binding has occured.

Comment: Ok finally i got it. Had to include the script in the footer via wp_enqueue_script. So now my script runs after the scripts which bind the event listener. And in my scripts i remove the listener with .off() and it works! Thanks a lot Michael

Comment: Glad you got it to work. I gave a more general answer that will hopefully be useful to others aswell. If you want, you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to unbind the event that triggers the second AJAX request. You need to make sure that your `unbind()` function is called *after* the event binding has occurred.

So why not just load it in the footer? One reason is that the other script that binds the event might be loading in the footer, too.

To control the loading order of scripts, you can actually use the `dependencies` parameter of [wp_enqueue_scripts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). You just need to know the handler of the script that you wish do add as a dependency:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-handler', 'script.js', array( 'another-script-handler' ) );
```

`my-handler` is now depending upon and is therefore loaded *after* `another-script-handler`.

Answer (score -2):

Remove this line of code
`window.location = 'main.php';`

Then it's better you use this

```
jQuery('#loginform').on('submit',function(e) {e.preventDefault();.....});
```

Than this that you have

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#loginform' ,function(e) {....})
```